# How to define a json struct type for function signature?

Tags: go, serialization, struct

I have a struct definition

```
type ds struct {
    name     string
    TagList                          []struct {
        Key   string `json:"Key"`
        Value string `json:"Value"`
    } `json:"TagList"`
}
```

I want to have a function that converts the TagList into string arrays (my own serialization function). So the function will look like this

```
func serialize(tagList <?>) string
```

What I should define as the type <?> is what I am not sure about. Because if I called this function using

```
serialize(mydata.TagList)  // mydata is the ds struct type
```

Then it will remind me that this type is []struct{...}

But I am not sure how to define the []struct{...}.

I am also open for existing serialization library apis i can use to do this as long as it serialized into a string.

Comment: *"I am also open for existing serialization library apis i can use to do this as long as it serialized into a string."* -- Use `encoding/json` from the stdlib.

Comment: *"But I am not sure how to define the []struct{...}."* -- `[]struct{ ... }` Is actually how.  (replace `...` with identical fields and types as the desired target type.

Comment: Your `TagList`'s type is a slice of **unnamed** structs. When you choose to use **unnamed** structs you choose *Inconvenience*. Declare the type instead, so that you can reference it by name.

Comment: However if `serialize` is supposed to accept and serialize other types as well, not just the one of the `TagList` field, then you can simply use the type `any`.

Comment: @mkopriva write that in code sample, and i cna take it as an asnwer. Thank you! I solved using your suggestion. name the struct and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is to declare a new type for the nested struct field so that you can reference the type by name whenever you need to; for example:

```
type Tag struct {
    Key   string `json:"Key"`
    Value string `json:"Value"`
}

type ds struct {
    name    string
    TagList []Tag `json:"TagList"`
}

// ...

func serialize(tagList []Tag) string {
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, without declaring the new type, one would have to repeat the whole type definition of the anonymous struct in every place where one wants to use that type; for example:

```golang
func serialize(tagList []struct {
    Key   string `json:"Key"`
    Value string `json:"Value"`
}) string {
    // ...
}
```